# BQ Ubuntu Phone - How do I set media to save on a Micro SD storage card?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I have fitted a 32GB micro SD card into my new BQ Ubuntu phone.

The OS recognizes the SD card. But I can't see where I can specify for the phone to save media to the storage card instead of the phone.

Is there any way I can setup the Ubuntu Phone to automatically save images, media, etc to the storage card instead of the phone's internal memory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can set where to save the media from the camera like pivtures and videos.
Just go to the camera and down there is an option "SD" where you can select to save to SD card, external card. Down to left.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate? I see no option to use an SD card.

Comment: I added you an image.
As you can see apears down to the left with SD letters.

Comment: I found the option (as per the pic from Yami) to save to SD card once you swipe from the bottom when in camera mode